# How to change bootstrap grid order with full width columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to change the order of columns in bootstrap depending on the screen size, but with some full width columns. Without full width columns, it is a simple matter of using push and pull helper classes. I think that perhaps nesting is needed, but I've been staring at this, and it isn't coming to me!

**What I want:**

```
MD-LG:

[A][B][D]
[===C===]
```

-

```
SM:

[A] [B]
[==C==]
[==D==]
```

-

```
XS:

[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
```

Here is a jsbin sandbox of what I have going on so far:
http://jsbin.com/suqefecifi/edit?html,css,output

I was hoping that I could just push or pull and have it swap rows, but it seems those helper classes are only designed to change the order of columns within a single row.

I think that best strategy for coming up with a plan for things like this is to START with your XS order...that's the order the HTML needs to be in. From there, use helper classes to take care of the larger sizes. Or is there a better way to approach the problem? I'm looking for a better method than "stare at it and hope for an epiphany!"

Comment: I __think__ you can add more than 12 into 1 row and bootstrap is still clever enough to sort them. This way you can still use the push / pull helper classes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing in the jsbin link, and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the .visible- and .hidden- helper classes, intended for "toggling content acrosss viewport breakpoints", see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

You could add another column - let's call it 'E' - and set it to be visible on md and lg sizes, otherwise hidden. D would be set to be invisible at these sizes, otherwise visible.

The order of columns in your HTML would be ABECD, with column classes set appropriately. The aim would be that, in your first example (MD-LG), the client would see:

```
[A][B][E]
[===C===]
```

Comment: Yeah... I'm hoping for something more elegant. The content in that section is actually fairly complex, including a YouTube embedded video. I'm not terribly keen on having all of that twice on the page (even though one of them will always be hidden). It is a lot of extra overhead on the page.

Comment: I agree it's pretty horrible in that situation, I just can't think of another solution that solely uses Bootstrap markup.